# Flatten out a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's some data from another question:

```
     A  B    C
0    s  s  NaN
1  NaN  x    x
```

Trying to experiment, I would like to transform the dataframe to something like this:

```
       0
A      s  
A    NaN
B      s    
B      x
C    NaN    
C      x
```

As a dataframe, or series. This is equivalent to a transposition and reshape. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method is to use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
In[184]:
df.melt().set_index('variable')

Out[184]: 
         value
variable      
A            s
A          NaN
B            s
B            x
C          NaN
C            x
```

The [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) step is needed due to the intermediate result:

```
In[188]:
df.melt()

Out[188]: 
  variable value
0        A     s
1        A   NaN
2        B     s
3        B     x
4        C   NaN
5        C     x
```

Comment: The other answers are good, but yours wins for simplicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unstack by transposing the df i.e

```
df.T.unstack().to_frame().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
     0
A  s  
A  NaN
B  s  
B  x  
C  NaN
C  x  
In [620]:
```

Comment: You'll need `.sort_index` as well but not bad.

Comment: Do you want be to sort_index or is it fine?

Comment: For completeness sake, I would recommend adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply

```
df.stack(dropna=False).to_frame().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()

Out[44]: 
     0
A    s
A  NaN
B    s
B    x
C  NaN
C    x
```

Comment: Almost similar to mine but with stack approach.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Yes , just do not need `.T`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

---

`DataFrame.stack()` is the flattening method for dataframes. However, to preserve data, it leaves you with a MultiIndex. Since in your output frame, you did not need the original index, you can drop it with `reset_index`.

Comment: This drops `NaN` values.

Comment: Yeah, `stack` does that. It was actually a convenience for my needs. I did not see your question properly enough to realize you needed the `NaN`. Use @EdChum's answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added `stack(dropna=False)`